# Работа с формами на Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms

Не могу корректно реализовать добавление эмоджи в поле ввода текса. Django дает вводить текст либо в forms.TextInput() или forms.Textarea(), эмоджи хранятся в `<span style="background-image: url(../emoji.png)"></span>`, при попытке добавления, с использованием js, в поле ввода, отображается просто html код приведенный к типу данных str. В вк например поле ввода текста в чатах это `<div>` и  они добавляют эмоджи через `<img>`. Как реализовать добавление через Django форму, можно ее преобразовать так же к блоку например или есть условия при которых input.value или textarea.innerHTML отобразят html тег как мне это нужно?

Скрипт js:

```
    <script>
        var input_message = document.getElementById('id_message');
        var emoji_box = document.getElementById('emoji-box');
        var emoji_scroll_div = emoji_box.querySelector('.emoji-mart-scroll');
        emoji_scroll_div.addEventListener('mouseover', showemoji);
        function showemoji(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var emoji_targ = event.target;
            if (emoji_targ.closest('.emoji-mart-emoji')){
                var emoji_span = emoji_targ.closest('.emoji-mart-emoji');
                emoji_targ.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    input_message.value = emoji_span.innerHTML;
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Форма:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['message']
        labels = {
            'message': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'message': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Отображение формы:

```
<form id="message-form" class="panel panel-body" method="post">
                
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" 
     value="">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" required="" id="id_message">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="ico ico-comment"> 
    </span>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Реализация в вк для примера:

```
<div class="im_editable im-chat-input--text _im_text" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" id="im_editable0" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true">

"Привет&nbsp;" <img class="emoji" src="/emoji/e/f09f988a.png" alt="">

</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на widgets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/
Вам наверное придется написать свой основываясь на существующем или с 0